# facebook-php-sdk list my fb page admins works on localhost, not on production

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

The code below runs as expected on my local machine, but throws the following error on my production:

> Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be
>   used to query information about the current user.

I've double-checked my config, and page permissions but cannot find the reason.

```
   require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';
    $path               = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../conf/' . php_uname('n'). '.ini';
    $iniConfig          = parse_ini_file($path, true);
    $page_id            = $iniConfig['fb_theclient']['page_id'];

    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId'     => $iniConfig['fb_theclient']['appId'],
        'secret'    => $iniConfig['fb_theclient']['secret']
    ));

    $user               = $facebook->getUser();
    $page_info          = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token');

     if( !empty($page_info['access_token']) ) {  # if we have access_token,
         $args = array(
             'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
             'scope'         => 'publish_stream, manage_pages'
         );
     }
         # Get our admins info
        $a_admins  = $facebook->api('/' . $page_id .'/admins', 'get', $args);

        foreach($a_admins['data'] as $thisadmin){
            $myadmin[] = array('name' => $thisadmin['name'], 'id '=> $thisadmin['id']);
        }

    print_a($myadmin);

function print_a($arr){

    echo "<PRE>";
    print_r($arr);
    echo "</PRE>";

}
```

Comment: The code looks fine to me, can you specify on which call you get the error? you're attempting to make a API call with **no `accesss_token`**

Comment: Ok, its not getting access_token with $page_info. Only returns id in the $page_info array. Am I not asking for the access_token correctly?

Comment: _"its not getting access_token with $page_info. Only returns id in the $page_info array"_ Because the user is not authenticated!

Comment: So, I need to authenticate 'me' even though I want to access my page?

Comment: Yeah, you can't access any type of data of a user without a `access_token` with required permissions